# JQuery load with socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, socket.io

Hello I want to make an application on socket.io with HTML and JQuery. My server creator is :

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/views/index.html'));
}).listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('Listening at: http://localhost:8080');
});
```

and my HTML that contains script tags :

```
<script charset="UTF-8" src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

With these initals I get an error 
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <** on jquery.min.cs:1

I can load socket.io but jquery.min.cs is not loading on a local source.
I understand that, with res.end jquery.min.cs loads my index.html but i can't solve it.
Please help me, thank you.